# Same CSS file produces different results in chrome and firefox

Tags: css

I've updated (changed color code for a few tags)a css file on my server but when I load my site on chrome it still loads the previous version of the css file. I've cleared cache and history of the browser but still nothing.

However when I load the site on firefox, part of the changes I've made are loaded. But part of the site still shows previous version of the css file.

The files are hosted on Godaddy.

Any suggestion on why that is?

Thanks

Example
This is the code on the server

```
#ose-login-box .x-panel-header{
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top , #ED6F6D 0%, #ED6F6D 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #ED6F6D;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top , #ED6F6D 0%, #ED6F6D 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #ED6F6D;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top , #ED6F6D 0%, #ED6F6D 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #ED6F6D;
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top , #ED6F6D 0%, #ED6F6D 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #ED6F6D;
  background: linear-gradient(top , #ED6F6D 0%, #ED6F6D 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #ED6F6D;
  background-color: #ED6F6D;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 2, 0.6);
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:110%;
  font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:700;margin:0;
  padding:10px 15px
}
```

This is the code I see in Chrome when I inspect element

```
#ose-login-box .x-panel-header{
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #485565 20.86%, #485565 45.03%) repeat scroll 0 0 #485565;  
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top , #485565 0%, #485565 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #485565; 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top , #485565 0%, #485565 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #485565; 
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top , #485565 0%, #485565 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #485565; 
  background: linear-gradient(top , #485565 0%, #485565 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #485565;
  background-color: #485565;  
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 2, 0.6);
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:110%;
  font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:700;
  margin:0;
  padding:10px 15px;
}
```

**Update:** Just check on the server and I got this message "Missing vendor-prefixed CSS gradients for Old Webkit (Safari 4+, Chrome)"

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: possible to provide link or some code or references?

Comment: CTRL + f5 refresh and see if that fixes it.

Comment: when the page is accessible to the public just provide the link

Comment: Code Added. Also the page can be viewed at http://wallstanalyst.com/login

Comment: Have you tried to add the old syntax for chrome and safari `-webkit-gradient`?